# OpenSSL and Bouncy Castle CMS implementation

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle

I'm porting some code from Java to C++ and noticed some difference in CMS generation. In OpenSSL if I use `CMS_sign(X509 *signcert, EVP_PKEY *pkey, STACK_OF(X509) *certs, BIO *data, unsigned int flags)` and provide `pkey` with public key different from public key of signer certificate `signcert` I getting validation error and that is right.

If I do the same thing with `CMSSignedDataGenerator` class I will get SignedData without any errors. Here is code example:

```
CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
DigestCalculatorProvider dp = new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider(CryptoUtils.BC).build();
JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder builder = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(dp);
ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(cert.getSigAlgName()).setProvider(CryptoUtils.BC).build(privateKey); 
gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(builder.build(signer, cert));
CMSSignedData s = gen.generate(msg, true);
```

In this code example I use certificate with public key not same as public key from private key object and no any exceptions or validation errors. Is it OK or not?

Comment: What happens when you try to validate produced CMS later with other tools i.e. OpenSSL? Validation fails?

Comment: I could try to test such case. More interesting to my is why BC allows to produce CMS with wrong keys.